# Installation of FinchTV in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04

I am using Ubuntu 20.04.3.
I need to install FinchTV in it.
Is there any way to get the software?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This FinchTV [application](https://digitalworldbiology.com/FinchTV) is available only for macOS and MS Windows. To run it on Ubuntu you need Wine - you have to install it using PlayOnLinux by following the below steps:

1. Install PlayOnLinux with

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install playonlinux
   ```
2. Obtain Windows installer package from official site:

   ```
   cd ~/Downloads
   wget -c https://digitalworldbiology.com/sites/default/files/Basic%20page/upfiles/Windows_FinchTV_1_4_0.zip
   unzip Windows_FinchTV_1_4_0.zip
   ```
3. Launch PlayOnLinux
4. Click *Install*, select *Install a non-listed application*
5. Follow the wizard, press *Next* 4 times
6. Specify a name of wine virtual drive, i.e. *`finchtv`*, click *Next* 3 times
7. Click *Browse* and specify path to installer - *`~/Downloads/FinchTV_1_4_0/Installer.msi`*, click *Next*
8. Follow FinchTV windows installer with all default settings
9. Create shortcut for *`FinchTV.exe`* then select *I don't want to make another shortcut*, click *Next*
10. Launch FinchTV using desktop shortcut and enjoy.

Answer (score 1):

For software that is not in the standard software repositories, you depend on the install documentation of the software you want to install. First ensure that the software is supported on linux in the first place. If that is the case, installation can take different forms. You may need to compile the software yourself, the developer may provide binary files you can install using an install script, the developper may provide a `.deb` installation file, or even a software PPA, ... Only you can know, studying the documentation provided by the software.